# Why does the W3C Validator not take <?php include() tags in HTML5?

Tags: php, html, validation

I was trying to validate a simple HTML5 page, and it successfully validates everything except three instances of `<?php include` statements which are marked as errors. I can't figure out what makes it not take the PHP tags. Why would this be? Below are the three errors it outputs:

```
Validation Output: 3 Errors

 Line 29, Column 5: Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)
            <?php include("inc/main-menu.php"); ?>

 Line 87, Column 9: Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)
        2007-<?php echo date("Y"); ?> 

 Line 94, Column 3: Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)
    <?php include_once("inc/analytics.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Did you explicitly force HTML5 mode? Looks to me like standard SGML parsing...

Comment: If your server's set up correctly to serve PHP, simply renaming test.html to test.php should cause the PHP to actually be executed and resolve this.

Comment: I guess your bigger problem is that your page isn't evaluated as PHP by your server. The failing HTML validation is just a smaller symptom.

Comment: Yep, I needed to change the extension to .php. Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those PHP tags should not show up in your markup. They'll be written in your code, but only your web server should see those -the page generated by your server will not have those tags visible.

I'm guessing you are copying your source and pasting into the validator? Try viewing the page in your browser instead (assuming you are running a local web server, like Wamp or Xampp), view source, and then copy and paste that code, instead of directly from your editor.

Comment: Here's the links to wamp and xampp, in case you don't have one of those yet:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: There's a link to the page in the question.

Comment: @John - ah yes, good call. Well I see that the extension is .html. You can set up your server to read PHP in .html, but that's not standard. Try changing the extension to .php and, again, be sure your using a web server to view the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason I thought that the validator wouldn't take .php pages, but after renaming and entering the url it works great and passes with no errors and one warning (html5 is experimental).

Answer (score 3):

`<?php` is not valid HTML in any dialect. An HTML parser should never see `<?php` tags, since they're evaluated on the server. As such, it's correct that the validator complains.

Comment: Yep, the problem was the extension. I had to change it to .php.

Comment: Actually, both SGML and XML support processing instructions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction), which is basically any code enclosed within '<?' and '?>'. These nodes are exposed in the Document Object Model as Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE and have their own XPath instruction. Although it's recommended not to use them in HTML served to a browser (because some browsers print their content), I've seen no spec that explicitly prohibits the use of processing instructions in any dialect of HTML. If you do know about such a spec, please reference it.

Comment: @JohnSlegers It's been a few years, but in case it helps anyone:  The HTML spec prohibits this.  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#syntax-tag-name  Tags must start with '<' and be followed by ASCII alpha-numeric characters.  It is defined exhaustively and does not permit "?".

Comment: @SirRobert : It seems you're right. Strange that both SMGL & XML support it but HTML (which is SMGL) doesn't... even though HTML can embed SVG (which is XML). Anyway, if your want your HTML to be valid and to run fine in the browser, alternatives to processing iinstructions would be (1) using HTML comments or (2) using custom HTML tags... although such an approach is still kinda hacky and not something I'd recommend. You're probably better off just using plain old vanilla JavaScript, a template engine like mustache or a UI framework like React to achieve whatever you're going for...

Answer (score 1):

`<\?php include() ?>` is PHP tag which needs to be rendered by PHP processor. It's not a valid HTML tag

Comment: How do I render it by a PHP processor?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the W3C validator will always mark pages with  ANY php, as errors? How do I use php code but also validate properly?

Comment: It means that the extension have to be .php and the server needs to be able to render PHP.

Comment: To do that you need to set up your server to render php. and change the extension from .html to .php

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I changed it to .php and it worked fine.